# How is the cardinality of this set odd?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I don't understand how the cardinality can be odd:

Q is a non-explicitly defined set.

$|{x \in P(Q): |X| \le 2}| = 29$

Comment: Why should it be even?

Comment: I think there is more information regarding $Q$ that is needed in order to determine the cardinality. For example, even without the elements being explicitly stated, do you know how many elements are in $Q$?

Comment: Well, for example, if $Q$ had $3$ elements, you would have $1$ subset with $0$ elements, $3$ subsets with $1$ element, and $3$ subsets with $2$ elements, giving a total of $7$, is odd.

Comment: End goal of question is to determine cardinality of Q, but I don't just want the answer. I understand that cardinality of power-sets are 2^n where n is the cardinality of the set. So |X| less than or equal to 2 would be = {-2,-1,0,1,2}. I don't understand how X being a member of the power-set of Q can make the cardinality 29.

Comment: What do you mean, "$\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$"? No, no. $|X|$ means "the cardinality of $X$" (not absolute value!); the number of elements that $X$ has. So you are being told that if you count the number of subsets that have at most two elements in it, then you get $29$ distinct such subsets.

Comment: (Also, there are numbers other than integers, so if you really had "absolute value of $X$ less than or equal to $2$", then you would have more than just those five integers....)

Comment: Was taught that Vertical bars represent cardinality when refering to a set, and absolute value when referring to members of a set. Is that wrong?

Comment: Okay, I see my mistake. X is infact a set, because it is a member of a powerset. Hence vertical bars are still referring to cordinality. Thank you!

Comment: "Was taught that Vertical bars represent cardinality when refering to a set, and absolute value when referring to members of a set. Is that wrong?"  Kind of.  What if the member of a set is itself a set?  Or what if it is a set of things that are not numbers?  $P(Q)$ is the set of subsets of $Q$ So $x \in P(Q)$ means that $x \subset Q$.  So $x$ is a set.   It is not a number.

Comment: @ArugulaSalad: It's absolutely wrong; the meaning of the vertical bars is context dependent. In particular, it can only mean "absolute value" when you are refering to **real numbers**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|Q|=n$,  the number of subsets with at most $2$ elements is the sum of the number of subsets with $0, 1$ and $2$ elements:
$$\bigl|\{x ∈ \mathscr P(Q): |X| \le  2\}\bigr| = 1+\binom n1+\binom n2=1+\frac{n(n+1)}2,$$
and I don't see why $\dfrac{n(n+1)}2$ cannot be even. This depends  on $n\equiv 0, 3\mod 4$ or not.